# Store ScheduledJob in Document Folder Body and restore it back to activate it

Tags: apex

I want to get all active jobs from `CronTrigger` and store them in the Document Body, and restore it back to activate it.

Trying to automate activating and deactivating Scheduled Jobs. Don't know whats going on with AfterDeploy() method on this line:

```
json.deserialize(List(List<CronTrigger>)docBlob.toString().List<CronTrigger>.class);
```

---

```
public class AutoDeployment{ 

    public static void BeforeDeploy() {
        List<CronTrigger> crontrig = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, CronJobDetailId,  CronJobDetail.Id, CronJobDetail.Name, CronJobDetail.JobType 
                                      FROM CronTrigger 
                                      WHERE CronJobDetail.JobType = '7'];
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.FolderId = [SELECT Id FROM Folder WHERE DeveloperName = 'Folder_Name'].id;
        doc.Body = blob.valueOf(json.serialize(crontrig));
        doc.Name = 'DocumentUniqueName';
        System.debug('doc=' +doc);
        insert doc;
    }

    public static void AfterDeploy() {
        blob docBlob = [SELECT body FROM Document WHERE name = 'DocumentUniqueName'].body;
        insert json.deserialize(List(List<CronTrigger>)docBlob.toString().List<CronTrigger>.class);

        System.debug('end of postDeployScheduledJobs()');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to be more specific about desired and observed behavior, and where *specifically* you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

This simply won't work for two reasons. First, jobs can have a *state*, and this state cannot be retrieved from the CronTrigger object (or anywhere else for that matter). Second, CronTrigger is basically read-only. To activate a job, you use System.schedule or System.scheduleBatch, and to abort the job, System.abortJob.

Your best bet is to create a cooperative system to preemptively quit if jobs shouldn't do their thing:

```
public void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
  if(!ScheduleControl__c.getInstance().IsEnabled__c) {
    return;
  }
```

If you need this for another purpose... well, you're out of luck. There's no way to temporarily deactivate jobs and restore them later.